# Upgrading jenkins which installed on linux with rpm package

Tags: linux, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, cloudbees

I am looking for some document/steps for upgrading Jenkins which is installed on Linux with rpm packages. I tried to search but mostly I got only with war files. Can some one help me out with some easy steps how to upgrade Jenkins which is installed on Linux with rpm packages with having same jobs I have in old version

Thankful for your comments and help..

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3):

Add the follow lines to /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo

```
[jenkins]
name=Jenkins
baseurl=http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat
gpgcheck=1
```

so just

```
rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
yum update jenkins
```

To see a list of jenkins repositorys [acess here](http://pkg.jenkins.io/) and change you package manager accordingly.

To upgrade direct from a rpm package install the ThinBackup plugin [ThinBackup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup) on jenkins. Make the backup, install the new jenkins, install ThinBackup on new jenkins, restore the previously backup.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Joao Vitorino but my instance doesnthave any internet so how can I update rpm file. Can you give some more brief steps like step by step way it will be great. I am a beginner so...Thanks in advence